# Getting Friends ID with PIG Script - Text manipulation needed

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Here is my input

```
user0=242561&friend=6226&friend=93856&age=35&friend=35900
user1=242562&friend=6226&friend=93856&age=35&friend=35900
user2=242563&friend=6226&friend=93856&age=35&friend=35900&friend=33900&friend=34900
user3=242564&friend=6226&friend=93856&age=35&friend=35900&friend=35930&friend=35920&friend=35901
```

Notes and Requirement

- I need to remove the age=35
- I need to get the user with friends number associated with the user ( In input one row will have one user

The number of friends will be different and the maximum number of friends is not know

Expected result

```
user0=242562-6226,93856,35900
user1=242562-6226,93856,35900
user2=242562-6226,93856,35900,33900,34900
user3=242562-6226,93856,35900,35930,35920,35901
```

I tried some thing like this,but didnt worked

```
inputs  = LOAD  '/data/friends4' AS (line:chararray);
tokenized = FOREACH inputs GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line, '&')) AS parameter;
filtered = FILTER tokenized BY INDEXOF(parameter, 'age=') != 0;
dump filtered;
```

I am getting as

```
(user=242562)
(friend=6226)
(friend=93856)
(friend=35900)
(user1=242562)
(friend=6226)
(friend=93856)
(friend=35900)
(user2=242562)
(friend=6226)
(friend=93856)
(friend=35900)
(friend=33900)
(friend=34900)
(user3=242562)
(friend=6226)
(friend=93856)
(friend=35900)
(friend=35930)
(friend=35920)
(friend=35901)
```

Now I need the result as bellow, can some one please help in this

```
user0=242562-6226,93856,35900
user1=242562-6226,93856,35900
user2=242562-6226,93856,35900,33900,34900
user3=242562-6226,93856,35900,35930,35920,35901
```

Comment: what you are getting as output and what is 'parameter.$0'?

Comment: Hi Subodh, I updated the question and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can create UDF to handle it properly and easy way, although you can try with the below script, I am just adding a line in your script to replace the 'friend=' with ',' now you can create a UDF  which will split the String from the space than replace first ',' with '-'

```
inputs = LOAD '/data/friends4' AS (line:chararray);
tokenized = FOREACH inputs GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line, '&')) AS parameter;
filtered = FILTER tokenized BY INDEXOF(parameter, 'age=') != 0;

REPL1 = FOREACH filtered GENERATE REPLACE($0, 'friend=', ',');
dump REPL1;
```

**output**

```
(user0=242561)
(,6226)
(,93856)
(,35900 user1=242562)
(,6226)
(,93856)
(,35900 user2=242563)
(,6226)
(,93856)
(,35900)
(,33900)
(,34900 user3=242564)
(,6226)
(,93856)
(,35900)
(,35930)
(,35920)
(,35901)
```

Comment: Thank you Subodh , I was trying to create without UDF, I think then my thought was wrong . UDF is a right choice